# How to modify this SQL join to include all columns?

Tags: sql, database, join

I have these three tables for a little quiz. Each question has one correct and three wrong answers

```
Table Name:            Columns:
Questions                   QuestionID, QuestionText, 
                            AnswerID (this stores id of correct answer)

Answers                     AnswerID, AnswerText, QuestionID
QuestionsAnswers            QuestionID,AnswerID
```

This query

```
SELECT QuestionText, AnswerText
FROM [Questions] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Answers]
ON Questions.QuestionID=Answers.AnswerID;
```

gives me the following result

```
What is the capital of England? London
What is the capital of France?  Paris
What is the capital of USA?         Washington
```

I actually need to see the other three wrong answers grouped with each question as well.
Kind of like

```
 What is the capital of England?    London
 What is the capital of England?    Berlin
 What is the capital of England?    BikiniBottom
 What is the capital of England?    Nottingham
 ... -- more results for France, USA and others follow
```

How can I modify my query above to get a similar result? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your table structure above, how about

```
SELECT QuestionText, AnswerText
FROM [Questions] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Answers]
ON Questions.QuestionID=Answers.QuestionID;
```

Note `Answers.QuestionID` not `Answers.AnswerID`

Comment: Thank you. All answers were good and worked, but yours came the fastest and also the last line with the note was important.Merci

Answer (score 3):

> SELECT QuestionText, AnswerText
>   FROM [Answers] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Question]
>   ON Answers.QuestionID=Questions.QuestionID;

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT QuestionText, AnswerText
FROM [Questions] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Answers]
ON Questions.QuestionID=Answers.QuestionID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to join with `QuestionsAnswers` Try below solution

```
SELECT QuestionText, AnswerText
FROM [Questions] 
JOIN [QuestionsAnswers] ON QuestionsAnswers.QuestionID=QuestionsAnswers.AnswerID;
JOIN [Answers] ON QuestionsAnswers.AnswerID=Answers.AnswerID;
```